# Practicing the arithmetic-geometric means inequality

Tags: inequality, means

I am struggling with learning the AM-GM Inequality that is considered vital to know for math olympiads, contests, etc. I just don't really know when to use it, when it is necessary to use, the purpose of it, etc...

I know,

$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n}{ n} \ge (x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^{1/n}$$

I've watched a few videos on using the inequality for optimization problems and all, but still can't grasp it completely enough. I feel like either my understanding is still relatively poor to try a few problems, or that I'm missing a few prerequisites (a basic understanding of number theory, or perhaps other inequality concepts?)

I've watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSSBOgHO_dY), which kind of helped a bit. If someone could suggest some learning resources, or books regarding the AM-GM Inequality, that would be seriously wonderful.

Thanks so much.

**EDIT**: Having trouble with this part of Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class book.

It is written that
$$xy \le  \frac{x^2 }{2} + \frac{y^2 }{ 2}$$
which is correct. The author proceeds to say that this is a bit of a trivial statement, and that in order to extract more information from it, we replace x and y with their square roots. He then gets $4\sqrt{xy} \le  2x + 2y$.

I don't understand how he got that. The closest I got to it so far was,

$$xy \le (x^2/2) + (y^2/2)$$

$$2\sqrt{xy} \le  (\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2 + 2xy$$

getting,

$$2\sqrt{xy} \le x + y$$

while he gets,

$$4\sqrt{xy} \le 2x + 2y$$

I understand that his is just twice bigger on both sides, but what steps did he take to get to that? I don't understand what he did in general. Would be awesome if someone could guide me through this.

Thanks!

Comment: A good exposition of AM-GM is Chapter 2 of _The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class_ by J. Michael Steele.

Comment: I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: What's wrong with just substituting $\sqrt x$ and $\sqrt y$ for $x$ and $y$ (and then multiplying by four)? That seems rather simple. In fact, I have no clue what *you* do. In any event, if you have a separate question (like the one you edited in), you should ask it *as a separate question*.